# Why does the same win32.com GetObject call (same line of code) only in certain circumstances find 'SAPGUI' in the Running Object Table

Tags: python, excel, vba, winapi, sap-gui

While writing a generic function (for python and Excel vba) to return a available SAP session (existing or new) for further scripting, I encountered a strange behavior of the GetObject call when it comes to finding the `SAPGUI` object in the ROT.

- With a session open the function behaves as expected and returnes the desired session object
- With no SAP open the function opens one using `sapshut.exe` and returns the session object as well

### So far so good, but here comes the twist:

- After a session was created by `sapshcut.exe` the `win32.com.GetObject('SAPGUI')` call does no longer recognise sessions opened "by hand" *(meaning: When jou open the logon pad and start a session from there)*
- If the session is not closed it is recognised again if you rerun the function
- If you close the session the function opens and recognises a new one
- The only way to recognise a session opened "by hand" again is to restart the computer

### Here is a minimal code snippet which reproduces the problem for me:

```py
from os import system
from win32com.client import GetObject
from pywintypes import com_error
from time import sleep


def open_and_close_shortcut():
    # check if 'SAPGUI' is in Windows Running Object Table (and getting connection object)
    try:
        GetObject('SAPGUI').GetScriptingEngine.Children(0)
    # If not open then open with sapshcut.exe and single sign on (no Logon is opened)
    except com_error:
        system('start sapshcut.exe -system=<SID> -client=<CLI>')  # put in your system and client
        sleep(2)  # tweak the time a little if it is not sufficient
    # get 'SAPGUI' from Windows Running Object Table (and getting connection object)
    finally:
        con = GetObject('SAPGUI').GetScriptingEngine.Children(0)
        # get available session and open TAC MD04
        for session in con.Children:
            if not session.busy:
                session.StartTransaction("MD04")  # change to any TAC you can access
                return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    open_and_close_shortcut()
```

**please note:** I tried the same logic in Excel VBA and encountered the same behavior!

### Fastest way to get the strange behavior for me is:

1. open a SAP session and start the script (see if MD04 is opened to confirm a sucessfull run)
2. close SAP and rerun the script (SAP should pop up, if the transaction is not executed maby you need a longer `sleep()` value)
3. close SAP again and open again manually (I do it with the logon pad)

→ now the script should enter the exept statement even though SAP is open, resulting in a SAP error/popup saying the system is already open

### Can anyone explain this behavior to me and how to eliminate it?

**PS** I found a workaround by programatically opening the logon pad an starting the session from there which does work as expected. So maby there is a difference in a session from logon and sapshcut?! Which still is misterious because both sessions are at some point recognised by the same line of code...

Comment: GetObject is a wrapper over Windows' CoGetObject (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objbase/nf-objbase-cogetobject). Beyond that, it all depends on how SAP has implemented its COM server that responds to the moniker you pass to it, it's not Windows nor its API anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, i removed Windows API from the question!

Comment: This wasn't the intended outcome. The [tag:winapi] tag was correctly used here. The essence of Simon's comment is that the system provides the infrastructure but doesn't otherwise dictate what clients of said infrastructure do. If SAP decides to only register objects in the ROT under certain (presumably undocumented) circumstances, then that is an issue that SAP support needs to be made aware of. Stripping the [tag:winapi] tag from the question doesn't get you closer to a solution.

Comment: I did not remove the tag from the post but did change one of the first sentences in the question from _...I encountered a strange behavior of the Windows API..._ to _...I encountered a strange behavior of the GetObject call..._

Comment: Oh wait, I misinterpreted the edit plus comment. The edit literally just replaced *"Windows API"* for *"`GetObject`"*. That's not wrong in itself, but still points fingers at the wrong party. It's not the ROT (or its implementation) acting funny. It's SAP's use of the ROT.

Comment: @IInspectable thank you for your further input and clarification. Do you think that it is rather SAP not registering its object under some strange circumstances than that the problem is some kind of interferrence between sapshcut and logon as launchers? Because if you stick to one of these methods the problem does not occur...

Comment: It's hard to know what the core issue is. You could try enumerating the ROT (either manually or by using a [tool](https://alax.info/blog/1444)) and see if that uncovers anything.